# Combine two grep functions using AND operator

Tags: r, regex

I want to combine the following commands using AND operator:

```
grep("^ab", strings, value = TRUE)

grep("ab$", strings, value = TRUE)
```

Here is an example for OR operator
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/grep-for-multiple-pattern-td4685244.html#a4685247

Would you please advise?

Comment: `grepl("^ab.*ab$", strings)`? If the patterns are not non-overlapping or are order-unknown, then you'll need something like `grepl("^ab", strings) & grepl("ab$", strings)`.

Comment: There should be comment (in the question bosy please) about whether the character values of either "ab" or "abab" should be matched.

Comment: I think you're making assumptions about how regex works. It's not the same as a boolean operation.`|` is not an OR operator; it is something logically similar but functionally distinct called alternation. Please give examples of your input and expected output so we can properly answer your question.

Comment: Ok, just use `grep("^ab(.*ab)?$", strings, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

The search for an AND operator in regex (whether in R or elsewhere) can be a long and sad search. The boolean AND means that both of two statements have to be true. How would you apply that to regex? Consider the regex pattern "ab", in `grep("ab", strings)`. Even this simple pattern has several requirements, ALL of which have to be true. It has to have an "a", AND it has to have a "b", AND the "b" has to follow the "a" directly.

```
strings <- c("abraham, not ahab", "no it was ahab", 
             "abraham was the one they left on ceti alpha V", 
             "You're talking about Sherlock Holmes", "He tasks me", "ab")
grep("ab", strings, value = TRUE)
# [1] "abraham, not ahab"                            
# [2] "no it was ahab"                               
# [3] "abraham was the one they left on ceti alpha V"
# [4] "You're talking about Sherlock Holmes"         
# [5] "ab"
```

If what you'd like is to match strings that BOTH start with "ab" AND end with "ab", then @r2evans pattern will work for you: `grep("^ab.*ab$", strings, value = TRUE)` will show them to you. This means it starts with "ab", has zero or more other characters, and then ends with "ab".

```
grep("^ab.*ab$", strings, value = TRUE)
# [1] "abraham, not ahab"
# NOTICE THAT THIS DOESN'T MATCH "ab", despite "ab" being at the beginning
# AND the end
```

If what you'd like is to match all the strings that start with an "a" immediately followed by a "b", AND ALSO all those that end with an "a" immediately followed by a "b", then you actually want `grep("(^ab)|(ab$)", strings, value = TRUE)`

```
grep("^ab|ab$", strings, value = TRUE)
# [1] "abraham, not ahab"                            
# [2] "no it was ahab"                               
# [3] "abraham was the one they left on ceti alpha V"
# [4] "ab"
```

So what about that solitary "ab" case? What regex pattern would match that and only that?

```
grep("^ab$", strings, value = TRUE)
# [1] "ab"
```

In this case, we wanted all of the matches to BOTH start AND end with "ab", but it had to be the same "ab".  Of course, we could combine this with the other "AND" version, and get all of the matches where ab was at the start and ab was at the end:

```
grep("^ab$|^ab.*ab$", strings, value = TRUE)
# [1] "abraham, not ahab" "ab"
```

..and one more thing:
We can use @r2evans comment to demonstrate a sort of DeMorgan's law with regex. Notice that the pattern with the `|` metacharacter produces the same thing that you would by subsetting the `strings` object with the logical vector produced by combining both individual regex matches with a boolean AND:

```
strings[grepl("^ab", strings) & grepl("ab$", strings)]
# [1] "abraham, not ahab" "ab"
```

Here `grepl` returns a logical vector, and we use it twice. The first is `TRUE` for every element of `strings` that matches `"^ab"`, and the second for every element that matches `"ab$"`.  Combining those logical vectors with an `&` operator produces the same thing as a pattern with a `|` metacharacter.

Comment: There is the third possibility, that the String starts with ab, ends with ab, but is only "ab" ("^ab$"). But I don't know grep in R. Is `grep("^ab|ab$",` the same as  `grep("(^ab)|(ab$)",` or doesn't it match 'abb' or 'aab'?

Comment: try it out! I'll add that example.

Comment: Well that was fun. Feel free to upvote if it was helpful for you! -- says the guy that is so close to 1000.

Comment: incidentally, "aab" is equivalent to "no it was ahab" in this example, and "abb" is equivalent to "abraham was the one they left on ceti alpha V"

Comment: r tells me: `littler: Incomplete Line! Need more code! (2)` when I paste in line 1 to 4. Probably I need some boilerplate/include/-switch.

Comment: nope, just a copy paste error. Check your commas and parens

Comment: Well - it's just copy and paste. But don't mind - it's not important to me.

Comment: I meant I think you may have made a copy paste error. The code as is runs in my console. I double checked when I saw your comment. And thanks for the upvote if that was you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
grep("^ab(.*ab)?$", strings, value = TRUE)
```

The pattern matches a string that starts with `ab` and then has an optional substring ending with `ab` and then end of string should follow:

- `^` - start of string
- `ab` - an `ab` substring
- `(.*ab)?` - 1 or 0 repetitions (due to `?` quantifier) of

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
  - `ab` - an `ab` substring
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JlyIEF/1).